# Ubalanced panel data to balanced panel data in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS 9.2 I am currently working with a panel data set. I have a variable stating the year and a variable stating the individual. Some of the people do not appear every year and I want to get rid of these observations. A simplified version of it looks something like this:

1. Person        year
2. 1             2008
3. 1             2009
4. 1             2010
5. 2             2008
6. 2             2010
7. 3             2008
8. 3             2009
9. 3             2010

So in this case, I want to keep person 1 and 3 or stated otherwise, I want to delete the second person, because he does not appear in every year.

I hope this make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do it is a query with subquery  in PROC SQL:

```
data have;
    input person year;
    datalines;
1 2008
1 2009
1 2010
2 2008
2 2010
3 2008
3 2009
3 2010
;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
    select *
    from have
    where person in
        (select person
        from have
        group by person
        having min(year)=2008 and max(year)=2010 and count(distinct year)=3);
quit;
```

If minimum and maximum years are fixed for the entire dataset,, you can drop first two conditions in HAVING-clause and keep only COUNT(DISTINCT...).

Answer (score 0):

The data step solution, which is nearly identical to the SQL in its functionality:

```
data have;
    input person year;
    datalines;
1 2008
1 2009
1 2010
2 2008
2 2010
3 2008
3 2009
3 2010
;
run;
data want;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.person);
  set have;
  by person;
  if year ge 2008 and year le 2010 then yearcount+1;
end;
do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.person);
  set have;
  by person;
  if yearcount=3 then output;
end;
yearcount=0;
run;
```